# How to change disabled color of ElevatedButton and OutlinedButton

Tags: flutter

There's no such property in `ElevatedButton` and `OutlinedButton` widget to change the disabled color like a regular `RaisedButton`.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  disabledColor: Colors.brown, // Error
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `onSurface` property if you only want to change the disabled color (this property is also available in `OutlinedButton`).

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    onSurface: Colors.brown,
  ),
  child: Text('ElevatedButton'),
)
```

For more customizations, use `ButtonStyle`:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
        return Colors.brown; // Disabled color
      }
      return Colors.blue; // Regular color
    }),
  ),
  child: Text('ElevatedButton'),
)
```

---

To apply it for all the `ElevatedButton` in your app:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        onSurface: Colors.brown
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: How can I change border color of disabled ElevatedButton?

Comment: How to achieve the disabled border color behavior from the ThemeData?

Comment: @Soorya Use `ButtonStyle(side:  MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(...)` and return a `BorderSide` from the callback just like I did in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is deprecated. Now you can use the disabledForegroundColor and disabledBackgroundColor properties to control how your buttons look when disbaled.

Example:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    disabledForegroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
  ),
  child: Text('Disabled Elevated Button'),
)

OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    disabledForegroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
  ),
  child: Text('Disabled Outlined Button'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In situation where you want to set an elevated button theme within your app, you can use this:

```
ThemeData(
  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      onSurface: Colors.brown
  ),
  child: Text('ElevatedButton')
))
```

Comment: This doesn't apply it for all the buttons in the app, you'll need to use `ElevatedButtonThemeData`, check my answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad, the above has been changed to reflect the corrections

Comment: This again is not a good solution as you are already passing `null` to all the descendant `ElevatedButton` widgets the `Theme` object can have.

Comment: Definitely it isnt I had to edit and removed null, modified the Elevated button theme initially and forgot to remove the on pressed method